# como hacer un consulta mysql que entregue dos columnas y que una tenga el valor de la fila siguiente

Tags: mysql

necesito que alguien me ayude en como hacer un consulta mysql que entregue dos columnas y que una tenga el valor de la fila siguiente.

tengo los siguientes registros en esta tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y necesito hacer un SELECT el cual me entregue en una columna los valores de lat empezando del id 403 hacia abajo, y en otra columna los valores de lon pero que parta del id 401 hacia abajo. se entiende?

Saludos,
Matias

Comment: No, no se entiende. En general es difícil hacer una pregunta clara con una sola frase. Se necesitan más detalles concretos. Además de que se espera que compartas tus intentos también para ver una medida de esfuerzo.

Comment: Matias Navarrete bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que realices el [tour] para que conozcas como funciona el sitio y así ganas tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges). Revisa también [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida por la comunidad.

Comment: @sstan acabo de actualizar la información para que quede mas clara.

Comment: Se entiende.. hay dos problemas.. como vas a unir las tablas, porque vas a tener que hacer dos selects y unirlas por algo.. y la otra.. que vas a hacer con el registro que sobra de una de las tablas?

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer una *sub-consulta* donde:

1. Busques aquellos registros donde el `id` sea menor al del registro en cuestión
2. Ordenados descendentemente por  `id`
3. Y limites el resultado a `1`

Así por ejemplo:

```
SELECT A.lat, 
  (
     SELECT B.lon
     FROM `myTable` AS B
     WHERE B.id < A.id
     ORDER BY B.id DESC
     LIMIT 1
  ) AS lon
FROM `myTable` A
ORDER BY A.id DESC;
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64917/1)</kbd>